# Oracle XE returns false fetching a table with 1 milion of lines using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, benchmarking, oracle-xe

I am trying to create a benchmark using PDO::FETCH_LAZY on MySQL, Postgres, SQLServer and Oracle.

So (on Oracle) I've created this table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "TESTE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DATETIME" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
    "CHANNEL" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
    "VALUE" FLOAT(5)
   )
```

And used this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generate_data
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      v_i NUMBER(10,0) := 0; 
   BEGIN
      WHILE v_i < 1000000 
      LOOP 
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO teste
              ( datetime, value, channel )
              VALUES ( to_date('2010-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')+trunc(dbms_random.value(1,1000)), ROUND(dbms_random.value * 100, 2), 1 );
            v_i := v_i + 1 ;
         END;
      END LOOP;
   END;
END;
```

And have tried this code :

```
<?php

ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
include 'connection_oracle.php';

$statement   = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM teste');
$inicio = new DateTime('now');
print_mem();
$i = 0;
while($registro = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
    $i++;
}
$fim = new DateTime('now');
$diff = $fim->diff($inicio);

echo "total : {$diff->format("%H:%I:%S:%F")} i: {$i}";
print_mem();

function print_mem(){
   $mem_usage = memory_get_usage();
   $mem_peak = memory_get_peak_usage();
   echo 'The script is now using: <strong>' . formatBytes($mem_usage) . '</strong> of memory.<br>';
   echo 'Peak usage: <strong>' . formatBytes($mem_peak) . '</strong> of memory.<br><br>';
}

function formatBytes($size){
  $base = log($size) / log(1024);
  $suffix = array("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB");
  $f_base = floor($base);
  return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), 1) . $suffix[$f_base];
}
```

Worked very well on MySQL, Postgres and SQLServer, but Oracle returns only false or 0 for count(*) using PDO. But, for strange reasons works well on SQL Developer (return 1000000 for count(*)).

So, is there any sort of limitation using Oracle XE on PHP PDO? Is there another way to surpass this or it is a pdo_oci bug?

Comment: Did you commit changes ? Try to run `commit` after running the  procedure. SQLDeveloper by default does not autocommit.

Comment: yes, and I've tested on sql developer and I have 1 million of lines there, but I cannot retrieve even one using pdo

Comment: Your script runs fine for me.  $i is 1000000, as expected.  There's no 'count' in your code, but if you mean https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php then check the doc: "For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement"

Comment: Oracle XE? @ChristopherJones and How long has taken with/without fetch_lazy ?